# What are some TeX-aware text editors I can download to my Windows 10 laptop, that would provide me with several autocompletion ameneties?

Tags: editors

I'm looking for an **autocompletion equipped** (explained below) TeX-aware text editor that I can download to my Windows 10 work laptop.

By **autocompletion equipped**, I mean: **it'd give me options to autocomplete and suggestions so that I don't have to do everything manually**, e.g. when I'm typing `\beg..`, it'd give me `\begin{}`, and when I'm typing `\begin{itemize}`, it'd understand that and come up with `\end{itemize}` as well. So, just to give a counterexample, I do *not* want an editor like TeXworks that's super basic, doesn't do any of the suggestions, autocompletion etc, and doesn't help me to write a document fast in any way. I want something *as similar* to the editor in https://www.sharelatex.com/, *except offline*.

*Since I'm on a work laptop, I'm now allowed to use online TeX editors like ShareLaTeX or OverLeaf*, so I need a similar one, but not online. Could you recommende me some *that're not too hard to use, and gets installed with all the dependencies?*

Comment: What do you mean by 'interactive' here? There are *lots* of editors listed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: @JosephWright I edited the question adding the necessary detail, hope that makes it more clear what I'm after. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your objectives are a bit ambiguous. E.g., in both the title and in the first sentence of the body of the posting, you state that you're looking for an "interactive TeX distribution" (whatever that may be), but then the remainder of the query appears to be exclusively about editors that provide various auto-completion amenities. The features of the editor should be pretty much independent of the TeX distribution, though, as TeX and LaTeX, etc are asynchronous and non-interactive. Please clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your comment, looks like I confused between the two. Yes indeed I want a downloadable editor that'd come with all the auto-completion  ameneties. I edited and clarified tha later in my question.

Comment: Thanks for providing these clarifications. I've taken the liberty of editing your posting some more, to further focus it on the editor's capabilities. Any serviceable TeX-aware editor should also be able to act as a "front end" to a modern TeX distribution, such as MikTeX and TeXLive.

Comment: As it stands, this seems to be a duplicate of the 'big list' question: there is no one 'best' editor

Comment: BTW, TeXworks does auto-completion (using Tab), though not suggestions: each editor will offer a differnt way of accessing similar features, so one has to be mindful that 'it's like X' won't always work.

Comment: @JosephWright Possible completions could count as suggestions ("If a partial keyword is given, repeatedly hitting TAB will cycle through possible completions." - Texworks manual, p 23). I like the Control-Tab cycling through cursor insertion positions. And the ability to define new keywords, with associated layout and insertions. Navigating between windows and synctex'ing between source and preview is probably more useful than mere auto-competion, as a feature. Not to mention scripting (QtScript, Lua, Python), for a diverse audience. Texworks is built on Qt4, so regex is available too (App C).

Comment: Unrelated - the fastest way for me to type a document is *not to type it at all*. Assembling a document structure is a structure in its own right. Example: if I find myself typing the same command sequence (either template or raw code) more than an arbitrary number of times, say six, then I think: "I'm doing this the *long* way. What's a better way?" After which, things like the autocorrect feature that is auto-complete plus  suggestions get left behind as beyond super-basic. It's all in the meta-process(es). But, people have to start somewhere. So everything has a purpose.

Comment: What I mean by "not typing code at all" is that, once one document (or style or code module) is set up and with a systematic naming convention (say, a Carian transliterator), then it becomes a template with placeholders (eg `XXX`, `YYY`), either for code-generation code, or for a Substitute/Replace function in a spreadsheet, so that producing the Lycian or Lydian version (say) is just a copy-paste. Alternatively, macros expand to the variant code with a parameter. Multivalent meta-code/process is probably a niche requirement, in the scheme of things. Auto-complete is useful for hand-typing.